# Comparing files based on version number and some other criteria and Formatting the output

Tags: powershell, dll, format, version, compareobject

I am comparing 2 files based on size, last write time and version number using *Compare-object* in Powershell. I am getting the results. The only problem is how to get the value of the version number from the result.

```
   function dll_compare(){
   param($path1,$path2) 
   $first = Get-ChildItem -Path $path1 -Filter *.dll
   $second =  Get-ChildItem -Path $path2 -Filter *.dll
   $diff = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $first -DifferenceObject $second -Property Name, Length, LastWriteTime, VersionInfo -PassThru  | Select Name, Length, LastWriteTime, sideindicator,@{n="path";e={$_.fullname}},@{n="VersionInfo";e={$_|Select-Object -ExpandProperty VersionInfo |Select-Object -Property Productversion}}
   $diff}
```

The result is in the following format: I want the versioninfo to contain the value, instead of "@{ProductVersion=10.0.10240.16384}"

```
Name          : PhotoViewer.dll    
Length        : 1827328    
LastWriteTime : 7/10/2015 4:31:20 PM    
SideIndicator : <=    
path          : D:\Site1\Dlls\PhotoViewer.dll    
VersionInfo   : @{ProductVersion=10.0.10240.16384}
```

Comment: $VersionInfo.ProductVersion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
$diff = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $first -DifferenceObject $second -Property Name, Length, LastWriteTime, VersionInfo -PassThru  | Select Name, Length, LastWriteTime, sideindicator,@{n="path";e={$_.fullname}},@{n="VersionInfo";e={$_|Select-Object -ExpandProperty VersionInfo |Select-Object -Property Productversion}
```

with

```
$diff = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $first -DifferenceObject $second -Property Name, Length, LastWriteTime, VersionInfo -PassThru |
    Select Name, Length, LastWriteTime, sideindicator,@{n = "path"; e ={ $_.fullname }}, @{n = "VersionInfo"; e = { $_.VersionInfo.Productversion }
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. I had 1 more question regarding this. The files used are saved on remote server, and this query is taking too long. Is there a way to reduce the time for this query?